# Wordpress nginx / htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

We have a Wordpress website serving some PDFs to logged in members.
For that to be possible, the hosting company has a rule in nginx and we have to place the protected files in **wp-content/uploads/membersonly**

```
set $is_uri 0;
set $is_logged 0;
if ( $request_uri ~* "wp-content/uploads/membersonly" ) {
set $is_uri 1;
} 
if ($http_cookie ~ "wordpress_logged_in") {
set $is_logged 1;
}
set $conditional "$is_uri:$is_logged";
if ($conditional = "1:0") {
return 403;
break;
}
```

We don't have access to the nginx configuration, I believe it's a shared hosting, but we would like to customize that 403 page.
Right now it looks like the server it's broken.
It would be nice to have something like

> **Content restricted**
> This content is only available to members
> **Login or Register**

That's impossible because - like I said - we don't have access to nginx config and folder and htaccess cannot control that either.
I tried to add

```
ErrorDocument 403 /mycustom403.php
```

to .htaccess but nothing happens, I still see the uggly
[403 error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH9fO.jpg)

Is there anything I can do to customize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For nginx server .htaccess file will not work. It will only works for apache server. For nginx server you have to create custom config file for your domain name.